# Ignore case for all selects on cetain table

Tags: select, triggers, oracle10g, collation, case-insensitive

is there a way in Oracle 10g to set a case insensitive search and possibly also translate for all incoming selects over certain tables?

I have a select like this:

```
SELECT city.city_name as city,
    city.city_zip as zip,
    city.city_name || ' - ' || county.county_name as county
FROM T_ADDRESSFILLCITY city
JOIN T_ADDRESSFILLCOUNTY county ON county.countyid = city.countyid
WHERE LOWER(TRANSLATE(city.city_name, 'úüűůéěäáôöőóťčížďňšŕýľřĺąćęłńóśźż', 'uuuueeaaooootcizdnsrylrlacelnoszz')) LIKE LOWER(TRANSLATE({PARAM}, 'úüűůéěäáôöőóťčížďňšŕýľřĺąćęłńóśźż', 'uuuueeaaooootcizdnsrylrlacelnoszz'))
```

but I'd like to change it to this

```
SELECT city.city_name as city,
    city.city_zip as zip,
    city.city_name || ' - ' || county.county_name as county
FROM T_ADDRESSFILLCITY city
JOIN T_ADDRESSFILLCOUNTY county ON county.countyid = city.countyid
WHERE city.city_name LIKE {PARAM}
```

and have a database mechanism (collate?, trigger?) to do the ignore case and translate by default for all selects.

But this should only apply for specific tables, not the entire database.

I could not find anything. Thank you in advance for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to set:

```
 alter session set nls_comp='LINGUISTIC';
 alter session set nls_sort='BINARY_AI';
```

and then run the second query. This should provide a accent case insensitive search on LIKE. 
Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#CIHJBFAD

alternative is to use `convert`. e.g.:

```
where upper(convert(name, 'US7ASCII')) like upper(convert('%e%', 'US7ASCII'));
```

Comment: I was able to find this and it works perfect, thank you but I didn't use it because I am not sure how the alter session works. I think it will also affect all other selects performed on other tables, which is bad. I need something like this but it should only apply to specific tables. Also I am calling this select from application and I get a connection from a connection pool so i really dont know what  effect will alter session have.

Comment: @sando.lakatos unfortunatley you have to use a session setting for "like" operations, as NLSSORT wont work with it. You can grab a connection from the pool, set the params, run your query and then change them back again to prevent any side affects on the subsequent SQLs. one aletanative however is to cast the column+string to ascii. i.e. try `where upper(convert(name, 'US7ASCII')) like upper(convert('%e%', 'US7ASCII'));`

Comment: I thought it's possible to set such behavior on a table but guess not. I will try to play with the alter session then, the convert doesn't seem to work form me. Thank you for the answer.